# Not able to handle child rect mouse events in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a parent rectangle on top of it there is a child rectangle, both rectangles having mouse events but child rectangle is not taking any mouse event always parent rectangle is handling.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle{
        id: outerrect
        color: "green"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle{
            id: innerrect
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "lightblue"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("child")
                }
            }
        }
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onClicked: {
                console.log("parent")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Issue:

Not able to handle child rectangle mouse events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example and explanation for the property [`propagateComposedEvents` of `MouseArea QML Type`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop)

So, if you want to handle the click only by the child rectangle you can change the order of the `MouseArea` block in the parent and the child `Rectangle` block. It changes the order of handling events by blocks.

To activate both handlers the top object should have `propagateComposedEvents: true` property and also `mouse.accepted = false` should be set in the `onClicked` handler, for example:

```
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked: {
            mouse.accepted = false
            console.log("parent")
        }
    }
```